# Pandas - mark duplicate elements in a list with an increasing suffix

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, data-manipulation

Given the following:

```py
from io import StringIO

csv = """\
col1,col2,col3
a,x,0.556281869
b,y,0.24783546399999998
c,z,0.010661738999999998
d,r,0.7982442009999999
a,p,0.642690298
f,q,0.734872757
c,t,0.432764343
a,g,0.37042963
"""
df_from = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv))

csv = """\
col1,col2,col3
a,x,0.42584888
b,y,0.938256412
c,z,0.339138513
d,r,0.16887348600000002
a_2,p,0.18562532199999998
f,q,0.289833661
c,t,0.108988277
a_3,g,0.861110437
"""
df_to = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv))
```

Which looks as

```
# df_from
  col1 col2      col3
0    a    x  0.556282
1    b    y  0.247835
2    c    z  0.010662
3    d    r  0.798244
4    a    p  0.642690
5    f    q  0.734873
6    c    t  0.432764
7    a    g  0.370430

# df_to
  col1 col2      col3
0    a    x  0.425849
1    b    y  0.938256
2    c    z  0.339139
3    d    r  0.168873
4  a_2    p  0.185625
5    f    q  0.289834
6    c    t  0.108988
7  a_3    g  0.861110
```

I would like to be able to create `df_to` based on `df_from`, I'm aware of `duplicated()`, but I don't know how to go about applying this in a way which will add the suffix as needed, because all though these `a` values are duplicated they're distinct things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter, add `1` because by default is counts from `0`, convert to string, prepend `_` and last remove `_1` values (first values):

```
s = df_from.groupby('col1').cumcount().add(1).astype(str)
df_from['col1'] += ('_' + s).replace('_1', '')
print (df_from)
  col1 col2      col3
0    a    x  0.556282
1    b    y  0.247835
2    c    z  0.010662
3    d    r  0.798244
4  a_2    p  0.642690
5    f    q  0.734873
6  c_2    t  0.432764
7  a_3    g  0.370430
```

Or if want only add new values for duplicated values created by [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) use similar solution:

```
mask = df_from['col1'].duplicated()
s1 = '_' + df_from[mask].groupby('col1').cumcount().add(2).astype(str)
df_from.loc[mask, 'col1'] += s1
print (df_from)
  col1 col2      col3
0    a    x  0.556282
1    b    y  0.247835
2    c    z  0.010662
3    d    r  0.798244
4  a_2    p  0.642690
5    f    q  0.734873
6  c_2    t  0.432764
7  a_3    g  0.370430
```

Answer (score 2):

We can do it by two steps , 1st `groupby` with `cumcount` , then `mask`

```
s='_'+df_from.groupby('col1').cumcount().add(1).astype(str)
df_from.col1+=s.mask(s=='_1','')
df_from
Out[290]: 
  col1 col2      col3
0    a    x  0.556282
1    b    y  0.247835
2    c    z  0.010662
3    d    r  0.798244
4  a_2    p  0.642690
5    f    q  0.734873
6  c_2    t  0.432764
7  a_3    g  0.370430
```